# How to handle untrusted certificate in firefox using Selenium Web Driver?

Tags: selenium, certificate

I'm facing some issues while handling "Untrusted Certificate" in firefox.
We can't use FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxProfile) as it is deprecated

I used the following code but couldn't achieve it.

```
    FirefoxProfile profile=new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
    profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
    FirefoxOptions options=new FirefoxOptions().setProfile(new FirefoxProfile());
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(options);
    driver.get("Web Link");
```

Could anyone suggest me the solution to achieve in Selenium 3.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in Firefox

```
DesiredCapabilities handlSSLErr = DesiredCapabilities.firefox ();       
    handlSSLErr.setCapability (CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver (handlSSLErr);
    driver.get("Your URL link");
```

For chrome

```
   DesiredCapabilities handlSSLErr = DesiredCapabilities.chrome ();       
    handlSSLErr.setCapability (CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver (handlSSLErr);
    driver.get("Your URL link");
```

Answer (score 0):

Below works fine for me

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities().merge(DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
cap.acceptInsecureCerts();
FirefoxDriver driverF = new FirefoxDriver(cap);
driverF.get("https://expired.badssl.com/");
```